# How can I get all the combinations of a list given that two items can not be in the same list?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am currently trying to find all possible sets of a list of numbers where two or more elements in the set can NOT be in the same set.

For example, I have an original list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and I have a list of sets [{1,2}, {3,4}], meaning that 1 and 2 can not be in the same set and 3 and 4 can not be in the same set.

Given those two inputs, result of the program should be:

```
{1, 6, 3, 5}
{1, 6, 4, 5}
{2, 6, 3, 5}
{2, 6, 4, 5}
```

Order does not matter in the final output.

Edit: I rewrote the implementation (without recursion this time). Now I am getting an error that says that I can't remove something from the list because it is not there...

```
def schedules(overlaps, complete):
print(complete)
final = complete.copy()
print(final)
for sch in complete:
    print(sch)
    for over in overlaps:
        if (over[0] in sch) and (over[1] in sch):
            print("This is an overlap!!!")
            final.remove(sch)
return final
```

Here is the error and output of the above code:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 2, 4, 
6), (1, 2, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5, 6), (1, 4, 
5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5, 6), (3, 
4, 5, 6)]

[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 2, 4, 
6), (1, 2, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5, 6), (1, 4, 
5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5, 6), (3, 
4, 5, 6)]
(1, 2, 3, 4)
This is an overlap!!!
This is an overlap!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schedule.py", line 24, in <module>
    result = schedules(overlaps, list(comb))
  File "schedule.py", line 19, in schedules
    final.remove(sch)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Edit: Adding a try, except block around final.remove(sch) removed the error but as noted in the comments below this code will NOT work if there are more then two elements in an overlap set. For example: if overlaps is now [{1,2}, {3,4,5}] the output should be:

```
{1,6,3}
{1,6,5}
{1,6,4}
{1,6,5}
{2,6,3}
{2,6,5}
{2,6,4}
{2,6,5}
```

Comment: does the order have a meaning in your example? i mean that 6 comes second, or are those just sets?

Comment: You tried to do something and it did not work. Good, you can try asking about it on stackoverflow. The way to do it is: paste the code you tried and the error you got. Don't just ask someone to implement this for you because you couldn't, without showing what you did.

Comment: You can start from the list of combinations and then eliminate the sets that you don't like: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I agree with you. I started implementing that and then got a little stuck. Also wondering if there is a better way to implement my function, for learning purposes

Comment: @zvone Code is posted! I didn't post my other solution because it was obviously trash I was honestly a bit embarrassed.

Comment: `final.remove(sch)` may be executed multiple times for the same `sch`, because of the inner loop. You should put a `break` after it, so that it does not continue with the inner loop after removing `sch`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with an arbitrary number of sets of arbitrary length, removing just 1 element of each set at a time from the list. The two versions below produce the same result, with the second using a a single list comprehension, which, while concise, is a bit hard to read.

First it filters the list of sets to get only those that are subsets of the original list. Then it uses `itertools.product` to derive all combinations using 1 element from each set, then for each result removes those elements from the original list.

```
from itertools import product

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
test_sets = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}]

result = []
subsets = [u for t in test_sets for u in combinations(t, 2) if set(u).issubset(set(l))]
for s in set(product(*subsets)) if len(test_sets) > 1 else subsets:
    result.append({r for r in l if r not in s})
print(result)
```

Result

```
[{2, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 6}]
```

Comment: Simplified it somewhat :-)

Comment: This will fail with `test_sets=[{1,2,3}]`

Comment: You're right. The question was posed as 2 or more elements can't be in the subset, where I did all the elements can't be in the subset. That makes it a bit more difficult.

Comment: Answer updated to work with your example and correspond better to the question, by using all combinations of two elements from any of the sets. The list comprehension version is even hairier but it works.

Comment: Hm, should it not contain several repetitions of the set that does not contain any of the elements present in the test_sets if `test_sets=[{1,2,3}]`?

Comment: It does indeed, with `test_sets=[{1,2,3}]`  you also get `{4,5,6}` as result now (even twice). Basically, in your earlier version the _hard_ part was done with the `set(product(*...` the only thing that remains to do is adding to each `s` all the elements from `l` that do not figure in any constraints from `test_sets`.  _This is then basically the suggested approach in my answer :)_

Comment: Yep. Thanks again. Jumped the gun. Tried again by basically coding around a single element list. By the way, your code fails with overlapping sets. This is a tough one but a good learning experience.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting further from the answer. Giving up now.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't consider the possibility of element repetition between the sets.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

- Start from the list of overlaps and create all permutations using only ever one element for each set.
- Add to each of the resulting list the elements from you initial list that do not figure in the overlaps.

**In python this basically boils down to 2 lines that work for an arbitrary number of sets of arbitrary length**:

```py
from itertools import product

init_list =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
overlaps = [{1,2}, {3,4}]

# the 2 lines:
rest = tuple(el for el in init_list if not any(el in ol for ol in overlaps))
[unique + rest for unique in product(*overlaps) if all(u in init_list for u in unique)]
```

```py
Out[7]: [(1, 3, 5, 6), (1, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
def schedules(overlaps, complete):
    final = complete.copy()
    for sch in complete:
        for over in overlaps:
            if (over[0] in sch) and (over[1] in sch):
                try:
                   final.remove(sch)
                except:
                   continue
    return final
```

The error in the question above was caused by me trying to remove the first list twice since it had two overlaps in it. I used a try, except block to get past it.

I wonder if there are better or more "pythonic" ways to do this. Let me know if you have any improvements!

Comment: Hi there, please [edit] your question to add this code.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from itertools import combinations  # to fill the rest of the sequence

# define a recursive function
# it begins to fill the sequences with the mutually exclusive sets
# but also tries to skip them
# it tries to construct only valid combinations
# so it should also perform for larger sets of numbers
def create_sequences(start_sequence, to_length, all_numbers, mutual_exclusive_sets, collect_sequences_in=None):
    # leave it up to the user if he want's to pass a list
    # if not just create one but for recursive calls just 
    # reuse the list to avoid garbage collection
    result= collect_sequences_in if collect_sequences_in is not None else list()
    curr_len= len(start_sequence)
    if curr_len == to_length:
        # well this is just for safety
        result.append(start_sequence)
        return result
    # create a working copy, so we can remove one item
    # (one set of elements which are mutually exclusive)
    # so we can pass it to the next recursion if needed
    # without spoiling anything
    mutual_exclusive_sets= list(mutual_exclusive_sets)
    if len(mutual_exclusive_sets) > 0:
        # there are mutually exclusive sets left, so grab
        # one, during this method call we will just work
        # with that set, adding 0 or one elements to the
        # sequence and leaving the rest up to a subsequent 
        # call (if adding one element doesn't complete 
        # the sequence)
        mutual_exclusive_set= mutual_exclusive_sets.pop()
        for value in mutual_exclusive_set:
            if value in start_sequence:
                # that may not be (should only happen if mual_exculsive_sets overlap)
                return result
        # ok so now call the function with the same sequence
        # after removing the one set (this is the case in which
        # we don't take any value from the set --> in your example
        # that wouldn't be necessary since it will not produce
        # a complete sequence and skip this anyways ;-)
        create_sequences(list(start_sequence), to_length, all_numbers, mutual_exclusive_sets, collect_sequences_in=result)
        # now the case that we take exactly one element from the set
        # and add it to the sequence
        for value in mutual_exclusive_set:
            work_sequence= start_sequence + [value]
            if len(work_sequence) == to_length:
                result.append(work_sequence)
            else:
                create_sequences(work_sequence, to_length, all_numbers, mutual_exclusive_sets, collect_sequences_in=result)
    elif to_length - curr_len <= len(all_numbers):
        # no mutual exclusive sets left, so now add from all_numbers
        for tup in combinations(all_numbers, to_length - curr_len):
            result.append(start_sequence + list(tup))
    else:
        # we would have to fill the sequence with items of all_numbers
        # but there are no sufficient elements, so skip this step and
        # leave result as it is (this was a dead-end --> like if we
        # chose to skip one of the mutually exclusive sets in your example
        # data --> but e.g. if you run the same with to_length=3 it is relevant)
        pass
    return result
```

for the following setup:

```
all_numbers= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
mutual_exclusive= [{1, 2}, {3, 4}]

all_numbers_tmp= list(all_numbers)
for me in mutual_exclusive:
    for n in me:
        all_numbers_tmp.remove(n)


create_sequences([], 4, all_numbers_tmp, mutual_exclusive)
```

It returns:

```
Out[27]: [[3, 1, 5, 6], [3, 2, 5, 6], [4, 1, 5, 6], [4, 2, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way to have your desired output using `combinations` from `itertools` module along with `all` and `any` functions:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_combs(ranges, forbidden, r):
    for comb in combinations(ranges, r):
        if not any(all(k in comb for k in elm) for elm in forbidden):
            yield set(comb)


ranges = range(1, 7)
forbidden = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
r = 4

combs = list(get_combs(ranges, forbidden, r))
print(combs)
```

Output:

```
[{1, 3, 5, 6}, {1, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}]
```

Comment: This will produce incorrect results if the original list is not of length 6, or if an element of forbidden list is not a subset of the original list, or the forbidden list has more than 2 elements.

Comment: This is why `ranges, forbidden and r` variables are dynamic inputs in this example. The OP need to add what he wants exactly. Besides of this this answer responds the OP example and the logic he/she just explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator. This solution first finds all combinations of the desired length, and then filters based on the matching `set`:

```
data, d1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [{1,2}, {3,4}]
l = len([i for b in d1 for i in b])
def _filter(_d):
  return all(len(_d&c) < 2 for c in d1)

def combo(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == l:
    yield c
  else:
    for i in filter(lambda x:x not in c, d):
      yield from combo(d, c+[i])

r = [i for i in combo(data) if _filter(set(i))]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 5, 6], [1, 3, 6, 5], [1, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4, 6, 5], [1, 5, 3, 6], [1, 5, 4, 6], [1, 5, 6, 3], [1, 5, 6, 4], [1, 6, 3, 5], [1, 6, 4, 5], [1, 6, 5, 3], [1, 6, 5, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6], [2, 3, 6, 5], [2, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6, 5], [2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 5, 4, 6], [2, 5, 6, 3], [2, 5, 6, 4], [2, 6, 3, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 5, 3], [2, 6, 5, 4], [3, 1, 5, 6], [3, 1, 6, 5], [3, 2, 5, 6], [3, 2, 6, 5], [3, 5, 1, 6], [3, 5, 2, 6], [3, 5, 6, 1], [3, 5, 6, 2], [3, 6, 1, 5], [3, 6, 2, 5], [3, 6, 5, 1], [3, 6, 5, 2], [4, 1, 5, 6], [4, 1, 6, 5], [4, 2, 5, 6], [4, 2, 6, 5], [4, 5, 1, 6], [4, 5, 2, 6], [4, 5, 6, 1], [4, 5, 6, 2], [4, 6, 1, 5], [4, 6, 2, 5], [4, 6, 5, 1], [4, 6, 5, 2], [5, 1, 3, 6], [5, 1, 4, 6], [5, 1, 6, 3], [5, 1, 6, 4], [5, 2, 3, 6], [5, 2, 4, 6], [5, 2, 6, 3], [5, 2, 6, 4], [5, 3, 1, 6], [5, 3, 2, 6], [5, 3, 6, 1], [5, 3, 6, 2], [5, 4, 1, 6], [5, 4, 2, 6], [5, 4, 6, 1], [5, 4, 6, 2], [5, 6, 1, 3], [5, 6, 1, 4], [5, 6, 2, 3], [5, 6, 2, 4], [5, 6, 3, 1], [5, 6, 3, 2], [5, 6, 4, 1], [5, 6, 4, 2], [6, 1, 3, 5], [6, 1, 4, 5], [6, 1, 5, 3], [6, 1, 5, 4], [6, 2, 3, 5], [6, 2, 4, 5], [6, 2, 5, 3], [6, 2, 5, 4], [6, 3, 1, 5], [6, 3, 2, 5], [6, 3, 5, 1], [6, 3, 5, 2], [6, 4, 1, 5], [6, 4, 2, 5], [6, 4, 5, 1], [6, 4, 5, 2], [6, 5, 1, 3], [6, 5, 1, 4], [6, 5, 2, 3], [6, 5, 2, 4], [6, 5, 3, 1], [6, 5, 3, 2], [6, 5, 4, 1], [6, 5, 4, 2]]
```

Comment: This doesn't match the output given in the original question. If two elements are in a set in the overlaps list (Ex. {1,2}) this means that those elements can NOT appear in the same list in the final output.

Comment: @TiffanyMontgomery Thank you for clarifying. Please see my recent edit.